# NHibernate loading symbols from SymbolSource.org

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, debug-symbols

I would like to be able to debug NHibernate and I have never loaded any symbols from `SymbolSource.org` before.

What url do I need to enter in Visual Studio to get it to load the symbols for NHibernate so that I can debug it properly?  I'm running version 3.2.0.4000 of NHibernate.

### Edit:

This is how I have it configured.

[image: Debug Options]

I see this in the output window.  Notice that it loads the symbols for Iesi.Collections but not NHibernate.

```
'QTAgent32.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\cwerner\TFS\Zeta\TestResults\cwerner_LKN030 2012-05-23 07_33_53\Out\NHibernate.dll'
'QTAgent32.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\cwerner\TFS\Zeta\TestResults\cwerner_LKN030 2012-05-23 07_33_53\Out\Iesi.Collections.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get your NHibernate 3.2 GA binaries from? Symbols for those were provided by SymbolSource by independently compiling the sources and reverse engineering PDBs - so results may vary. NHibernate has only started pushing official symbols since 3.3 CR1.

If you post a link to the actual binaries you're using, we might try to forge PDBs for those too, but only if it's any of the official distributions.

Comment: I use NuGet.  I am running version 3.2.0.4000

Answer (score 4):

Your version of NHibernate is present on the server of symbolsource.org.

How to config symbolsource.org see this link:

http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio

Symbolsource server url: `http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public`

Comment: This is what I tried initially but was unsuccessful.  It doesn't seem to load the symbols.  I see some symbols being loaded but not NHibernate.

Comment: I think it does not work because your platform is .Net 4.0 and symbolsource.org has only the .Net 3.5 symbols (http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.2.0.4000).

Comment: It looks like it's loading Iesi.Collections and I don't believe it has the 4.0 symbols.  You can see it loads the symbols above in my post for this.  http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/Iesi.Collections/3.2.0.4000

Comment: You are right! How do your "Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General" options look like?

Comment: Do you want to know any specific settings?