# debugging the FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to debug the third party dll, like `FluentNHibernate`?

Normally, its code is open source. Should I download the code source, then out the project in my solution folder, then replace the dll with the project reference, and only then be able to debug?

What if the `FluentnHibernate` will ask the `NHibernate` in its turn, should I need to download also the NHibernate code, and put it in my solution folder?

Actually, I downloaded both, and included both projects in my solution, but now `NHibernate` does not compile, because it does not find the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.... This one apparently requires `NANT` (I have no really idea what is this for or how to install it).... so I am a little bit lost in all this architecture...

I just want to find the meaning of an error that throws the FluentNHibernate, and with witch of my custom classes this error is linked.
I have an error like

> Tried to add property 'Description' when already added.

but I don't know about what concrete Description is the problem, because theere are multiple  Description s in different classes...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really need the source if you have the pdb files.  You can usually load them from the web.  Take a look at my question on this to see if it helps you:

[NHibernate loading symbols from SymbolSource.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708546/nhibernate-loading-symbols-from-symbolsource-org)